# Understanding einsum in Python

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

I'm using `einsum`, since it's very fast and saves me 2-3 lines of code each time I use it. But I'm having a hard time understanding it.

I'll give an example: I want to train a neural network. In order to compute something relevant to the gradient, I need to do the following:

Given a matrix `W` (line `i` column `j` is the weight on the connection from neuron `i` to neuron `j` in  next layer), and a vector of outputs of neurons `S` (hopefully the visual example at the bottom will help), I need to do the following:

`S[i]*W[i,:]` is a line in a new matrix

I figured out the following code gets it done:

```
 einsum('ji,kj->ij',W,S)
```

This makes sense to me now, but it took me a long time to get it right. A lot of trial and many errors (some things worked out but were wrong, some gave me errors when trying to run).

Now I want to compute a batch of these at once - that is, instead of `S` being a vector, it's a matrix of size `(NeuronsNum, BatchSize)` and I want to calculate:

```
einsum('ji,kj->ij',W,S[:,b])
```

for all `b=0` to `BatchSize-1`. And to save time (and understand `einsum`), I'd like to do it all at once and get the result as a matrix `(Neurons in layer l-1, Neurons in layer l, BatchSize)`.

I can't seem to get it right. So I appreciate you reading all this, and I'd appreciate any help I can get understanding this function

visual example:
[image]

The `i`th neuron sends some value, weighed by the strength of its connection to target. We do that for every `i`.

Comment: For neural network algorithms, `np.dot` is to be preferred to `np.einsum`. If NumPy is backed by a good BLAS, `dot` will blow `einsum` out of the water for matrix multiplication.

Comment: some of the things I need to do can't be done with `dot` (unless I make a few changes to the matrices and then change them back, which I'd rather not - because most of the code was written by someone else, and I'd rather not change it too much). Plus, I'd like to understand einsum anyway.
Also, I'd like to understand what is so wrong with my question that someone feels it should be downvoted.

Comment: if you write it out as you normally would do in for-loops (naive if you didnt know dotproducts existed in numpy etc), what does it look like? Thats how i do it when i try to use einsum. Once you have that written out, its just removing all the for-loop constructions and just keep the final C[i,j,k,l]+=A[m,n,o,p]*B[p,q,r] (but with the right indices at the right places ofc).

Comment: @usethedeathstar sounds simple enough. Didn't think about it that way. Thank you! If you'd like to write it as an answer i'll upvote and mark it as an answer :) Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain all the shapes of those things? I understand einsum, but not the problem you use :-)

Comment: We have `S` - a vector, and `W` - a matrix with as many rows as the vector. we want to multiply the `j`'th row of `W` by the `i`th element of `S`. That the first problem which I solved

The next problem is where you have multiple `S`s, and you want to do the same thing for all of them, as if there's seperate (That is, same problem, but doing it with multiple different `S`s at once)

Comment: @user1999728 I didn't downvote, but your question is rather broad. You're asking effectively "how to operate `einsum`" but `einsum` is a little language in itself. (A poorly documented one, I'll give you that -- my approach to it is currently trial and error too.)

Comment: @larsmans didn't mean to say it was you :P was just an off-topic thing.
Anyway, that was one of my problems - I've read the documentation a few times, and still I couldn't fully grasp the solution.

Comment: but than in your first case, that einsum notation is wrong? since there you got two indices for the vector and two for the matrix? while you should get one index for the vector and two for the matrix

Comment: It might be a matter of representation (vector vs matrix with only 1 row/column). It works for me. Wouldn't work without the indices since `shape(S)` is `(X,1)`, not just `(X,)`

Comment: "S[i]*W[i,:] is a line in a new matrix " For that you need numpy.einsum('i,ij->j',S,W) If your S is 1D and W is 2D, so theres a bug in your result somewhere still

Comment: but then the output isn't a matrix, it's summed up on the i axis, isn't it? I don't want it summed up

Comment: @user1999728 Ah, so you just want to pointwise multiply a vector with an array - in that case: numpy.einsum('i,ij->ij',S,W) should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write it out in nested for-loops, as if you didnt know numpy could do this, and than keep the indices for the numpy einsum. That way you have the exact formulation written down.

In your case:

```
R = einsum('ki,jk->kij',W,S)
```

will give you a 3d array, where the result, `R`, satisfies:

```
R[:,:,b] = einsum('ki,k->ki',W,S[:,b])
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `usethedeathstar`, I managed to find the solution:

```
einsum('ki,jk->kij',W,S)
```

will give me a 3d array, where the result, `R`, satisfies:

```
R[:,:,b]=einsum('ji,kj->ij',W,S[:,b])
```

His advice was: Write the code in a loop, that erase the loop, and you'll get the indexing!

Comment: well, `S[:,b]` is 2D. I just implemented some parts of someone else's code. They might have used `newaxis` to make the 1-D `S` vector 2D. As for the code here with `S[:,b]` - I haven't actually tried it, but I think it still depends on the data type. sometimes when I do this I still get a 2D array with only 1 line/column